# Blink Labelfield text in BlackBerry

Tags: animation, blackberry, java-me

How do I blink the LabelField text with a single color continuously? In Android it can be done with an AlphaAnimation. How do I do this on BlackBerry?

Answer (score 2):

Extend `LabelField` class and override its `paint(Graphics g)` method to draw/erase text upon consecutive calls.

Then implement a `TimerTask` and launch it with `Timer` class instance.

This task should invalidate your custom label field on regular basis, for example - for every second.

`invalidate()` call will cause the field repaint and label text will blink.

Comment: can u give any example for that.iam new to blackbeery app development

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to extend `LabelField`, you can schedule a `TimerTask` which will set an empty text and original text on the `LabelField` instance repeatedly. In that case the extent of the `LabelField` will be changed every time the text is changed. So, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12400021/431639) seems most perfect to me. Check a draft (not compiled, not tested) implementation of that answer.

***LabelField modification***

```
LabelField lbl = new LabelField() {
    private boolean blinkFlag = false;

    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        blinkFlag = !blinkFlag;
        if (blinkFlag == false) {
            super.paint(g);
        }  
    }
};
```

***Scheduling a TimerTask***

```
final int blinkInterval = 1000;

TimerTask blinkTask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {     
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
                lbl.invalidate();
            });
        }
    }
};


(new Timer()).schedule(blinkTask , blinkInterval);
```